# PayPal connectivity - Intermittent problems with PDT

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt

For the last 6 days (since 5/21/2014) we have been experiencing intermittent problems with our PDT call - resulting in either (403) Forbidden, or (503) Server Unavailable error codes from the PayPal servers.

We are getting the IPNs, but unfortunately this is causing real problems for us when the user returns to the site before we get the IPN, and it looks to them as if their payment has failed, which is not good for them.

Is anyone else experiencing such issues, and if so, does anyone know if it is flagged up to be fixed?

Thanks in advance

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently (9/16/2014). The solution from PayPal support was to add a User-Agent header to the request (minimum 5 characters).